# DB2 10 for z/OS where LIKE compare columns with wildchar '_'

Tags: regex, db2, sql-like

I need to do a select on DB2 like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE col1 LIKE col2
```

The problem is that DB2 doesn't support LIKE between columns, because the second operator must be static string.

I need to compare strings like these: 'AABGYD' and 'AA_G_D' that should match.
I can't use REGEXP_LIKE because not supported in this version.
Can achieve something like with other operators?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have zDB2 at hand to test, but it seems that it supports the [fn:matches](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/xml/src/tpc/db2z_fnmatches.html) function. 
Does the following work for you?

```
with t (col1, col2) as (
          select 'AABGYD', 'AA.G.D' from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all select 'AAGYD', 'AA.G.D' from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select *
from t
where xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches($s, $p)' passing col1 as "s", col2 as "p") as int)=1;
```